# SQL Server database on insert generate an key which already exist, Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a database generated by Entity Framework code-first. I have a table with 11000 rows and 5 columns.

The column `Id` is the primary key:

[image: table design]

On insert from an application (using EF), I got an error the first time; after some research I went to database in order to manually insert a record to see if it is working, and I get this error:

[image]

All columns are foreign keys and the value 1 exists for each.

Can someone tell me why I get this error?

Like I said, the table has already 11000 rows, not error on select query, no error on update, during insert the primary key generated by database is not correct!

The key 10987 exists!

[image]

Comment: What does "DBCC CHECKIDENT ('CandidatePositionStatus', NORESEED);"  give you? It'll just let us know what the identity value is currently at for that table. Also. what does "SELECT MAX(Id) FROM CandidatePositionStatus" give you?

Comment: this is the result: "Checking identity information: current identity value '10987', current column value '11000'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator."

Comment: Your id is off for some reason. So when you add a new record it's trying to reuse an existing one. Use "DBCC CHECKIDENT('CandidatePositionStatus', RESEED, 11000);"  so the next id value it tries to insert should be 11001, a new value.

Comment: now is working :). can you please insert your comment as answer, in order to accept it, thank you

Comment: what are the possible reasons for this issue?

Comment: I've never had anything change the IDENTITY value on me like that before. Maybe something went wrong with the EF code first process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your id is off for some reason. So when you add a new record it's trying to reuse an existing one. Use "DBCC CHECKIDENT('CandidatePositionStatus', RESEED, 11000);" so the next id value it tries to insert should be 11001, a new value.